# Regex similar to a Hearst Pattern in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to come up with a regex similiar to the [ones listed here](https://github.com/mmichelsonIF/hearst_patterns_python/blob/master/hearstPatterns/hearstPatterns.py#L26) for Hearst Patterns in order to get the following results:

```
NP_The_Eleventh_Air_Force is NP_a_Numbered_Air_Force of NP_the_United_States_Air_Force_Pacific_Air_Forces (NP_PACAF).
NP_The_Eleventh_Air_Force (NP_11_AF) is NP_a_Numbered_Air_Force of NP_the_United_States_Air_Force_Pacific_Air_Forces (NP_PACAF).
```

Doing `re.search(regex, sentence)` for each of this sentences I want to match this 2 groups`NP_The_Eleventh_Air_Force NP_a_Numbered_Air_Force`

This is my attempt but it doesn't get any matches:

```
(NP_\\w+ (, )?is (NP_\\w+ ?))
```

Comment: you could change `(, )` to `(, |\(\w+\) )`

Comment: @depperm doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both sentences I think `(, )?` is not present, but the part before between parenthesis is so you could make that part optional instead.

Also move the last parenthesis from `))` to `(NP_\w+)` to create the first group.

The pattern including the optional comma and space could be:

```
(NP_\w+)(?: \([^()]+\))? (?:, )?is (NP_\w+ ?)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J9KYe0/1)

If you don't need the space at the end and the comma space is not present, you pattern could be:

```
(NP_\w+)(?: \([^()]+\))? is (NP_\w+)
```

- `(NP_\w+)` Capture **group 1** Match NP_ and 1+ word chars
- `(?: \([^()]+\))?` Optionally match a space and a part with parenthesis
- `is`  Match literally
- `(NP_\w+)` Capture **group 2**  Match NP_ and 1+ word chars

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eAY8GT/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/PDqGsV)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"(NP_\w+)(?: \([^()]+\))? is (NP_\w+)"
test_str = "NP_The_Eleventh_Air_Force is NP_a_Numbered_Air_Force of NP_the_United_States_Air_Force_Pacific_Air_Forces (NP_PACAF)."
matches = re.search(regex, test_str)

if matches:
    print(matches.group(1))
    print(matches.group(2))
```

Output

```
NP_The_Eleventh_Air_Force
NP_a_Numbered_Air_Force
```

Answer (score 0):

I got one, quite simple:

```
regex = r"NP.\w+ ?Forces?\b
```

You can see how it works out, it's a online tool to write and test regex for multiple languages:

https://regex101.com/r/KKH3D3/1/